# What is "Vref" of ADC in a microcontroller datasheet?

Tags: adc, measurement, datasheet

I'm using an XMC4700 µC. I will connect a voltage divider to the input of the ADC to measure the voltage.
I found the equations to calculate the result. Only I'm not really sure what the \$V_{\text{ref}}\$ is.

The supply voltage of the µC is 3.3 V.

This is a link to the data sheet and a pic of the ADC operation conditions. Can you tell me if I have an internal \$V_{\text{ref}}\$ source? And what it is?

[Datasheet](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-XMC4700-XMC4800-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462518ffd850151908ea8db00b3)

[image: Screenshot of the datasheet]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Purpose of Vref in MCUs/ADCs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/589927/purpose-of-vref-in-mcus-adcs)

Answer (score 2):

You must provide the reference voltage, which will directly affect the accuracy of your ADC. You *could* use the supply voltage however that is usually a pretty crude and noisy reference source.

A reasonable choice would be an external 2.5V reference (either shunt or series type). You can go as low as 1.0V however accuracy will suffer, so it's best to use a relatively high reference voltage.

The Varef pin has high impedance when the converter is not operating, however it draws 30pC typically per conversion. The maximum current draw is about 65uA so if you want to not affect the accuracy by more than ~0.5 LSB with a 2.5V reference you need a maximum impedance of 5 ohms or so. Even an inexpensive TL431 will be okay at maximum conversion rate.

If you want tighter tolerance than the 0.5% or so best grade of TL431 then you can use a better reference.

Answer (score 1):

Page 38 of datasheet shows a VREF pin. Tie that to VDD. Your reported voltage will only be as accurate as the VDD. Also, connect 0.1uF across VREF to GND, to provide the charge needed during the conversion.

I see no mention of internal reference in the Table of Contents.

Some sensors are ratio-metric and thus tolerate variations in VREF.
Bridges, such as strain gauges, are one such sensor.
Thermisters, as part of voltage-divider across VDD to GND, is another.

Have you examined the code-spread caused by external noise sources that couple into your sensor, or into your wiring between sensor and ADC, or into your ADC IC? There is a paper discussing this, for a thermistor of 100Kohm; check on robustcircuitdesign.com

Comment: so as it seems, I don't have an internal Vref in the MC right?

Comment: Yes. I went through another document which was 18MB and found no Vref. ADC just survives with external ref.

Comment: Remember to filter and decouple with a RC circuit if you do not have a separate Vref regulator such as the 78L03.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an ADC reference voltage, to pin 33 (assuming LQFP-100).  That is Varef.